# Filtering Information from a google sheet back to a webapp

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, google-sheets, web-applications

I am creating a web app within Google Scripts to insert information into my a spreadsheet database. But if that item is already in my spreadsheet it will return some information letting me know that it has already been added. I have been able to get it to work returning two columns of information back to my webapp. My issue is that it seems like too much code for this.I would like to see if there is a way to make it compact. I tried using arrays, filter and for loop, but I couldn't get it work. 
I am learning javascript as I do this.

Any insight on this would be very appreciated.

```
function getSSinfo(studentid){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("SSDatabse");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(),10).getValues();

  var ssNameList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0];});

  var ssGroupList = data.map(function(r){ return r[7];});
  var position = ssNameList.indexOf(studentid);

    if(position > -1){
         return ssGroupList[position];
    } else {
     return 'no found';
  }
}


 function getSSinfo1(studentid){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("SSDatabse");
  var data = ws.getRange(1, 1, ws.getLastRow(),10).getValues();

  var ssNameList = data.map(function(r){ return r[0];});

  var ssGroupList = data.map(function(r){ return r[9];});
  var position = ssNameList.indexOf(studentid);
    if(position > -1){
         return ssGroupList[position];
    } else {
     return 'no found';
  }
}
```

```js
 function getInfo(){
       var studentname = document.getElementById("sid").value.trim();
         if (studentname.length >= 2){
            
            var gscript = {}
              gscript.usi = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSSinfo).getSSinfo(studentname);
              gscript.usi1 = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSSinfo1).getSSinfo1(studentname);
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSSinfo1).getSSinfo1(studentname);
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(updateSSinfo).getSSinfo(studentname);
        }
    }
   
    
 function updateSSinfo(ssinfo){
         document.getElementById("emailInfo").value = ssinfo;
  }
   
 function updateSSinfo1(sinfo){
         document.getElementById("test").value = sinfo;  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After studying your question I understand that you are using Sheets as a database. If that is the case, it isn't a good idea to use a spreadsheet as a database. I strongly recommend to use SQL databases instead, like [Google Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/), MySQL, Microsoft SQL Server or Oracle databases. You can connect those databases with your code using the [JDBC service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc).

Furthermore I actively advocate to use [batch methods](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet) instead of [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) to further optimize the data transfer. You can read more about batch operations [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices#use_batch_operations). Please, ask me any doubts so I can further help you.